# How to take data from a search bar and save it in a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

First of all, I am new to html/js/php. So please keep your answers as basic as possible. I have a project in which I have to make a replica of google home page and store the search history in a mysql database. The project is complete and only the backend part is left. I have created a database and made the necessary php file and also connected it to the database. But im having trouble in sending the data to the php file. Here is the html code for my form

```
 <form method="post" action="D:\xampp\htdocs\project\form.php"> 
 <input type="text" id="form_search" name="form_search" placeholder="Search Google or type URL"><aria-label="Search through site content">
```

Here is the code for my php file

```
 $search_history = $_POST['form_search'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO browsing_history (Sr_no, Search_History)  VALUES (0, '$search_history')";
```

But every time I run the php file, I get this error message and no data is stored in the database.

```
 >Warning: Undefined array key "form_search" in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\form.php on line 26
```

Please help me fix this error.

EDIT:-
I fixed the action path. I still have one problem. I have 2 buttons, google search and im feeling lucky. I have a javascript in the file that makes the google search button function like the actual button. When you search anything, it takes you to the search results just like google does. But the I'm feeling lucky button doesn't have any java script yet and is a simple submit type button. Now, when i type anything in the search bar and click **google search** button, it takes me to results but doesnt add data to the database. If I do the same but with **Im feeling lucky** button, it executes the php file and save the data. My question is, why is it happening? Is it because of the javascript? How can I fix this? Im learning these languages myself and therefore have little knowledge about them currently. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error One: Path to script

Comment: What do you mean by _“every time I run the php file”_? Are you executing it_manually_ somewhere? Because submitting your form certainly won’t do it, because there you specified a file system path as action, instead of an HTTP URL as required.

Comment: If I understood correctly your `form.php` both displays the form and accepts the form submission. If this is the case, when you access the form (on your browser) there are no post variables, therefore the `$_POST` array is empty. This array will only be non empty when you POST (submit a form with method POST) to a PHP script.

Comment: @CBroe please check my edit.

Comment: Please read about what SQL injection. Your code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use your form action as "http://localhost/Project/form.php

> And add the name attribute in the form tag name="your_form_name"

```
<form method="post" name="my_form" action="http://localhost/Project/form.php">
```

Comment: I did that but it still shows the same error. In the project, my search bar works exactly like the google search bar. With the help of javascript, the google search button takes you to the actual google results. But doesn't send data to the php file. Do you require to see any additional code to help me more?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the action sequence is wrong. try this

> action="form.php"

Comment: No, file paths are fine.